# When fragment calls fragment, who is the parent of second fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have started fragment A from my main activity and that fragment contains a button. When that button is clicked this code runs :

```
            Fragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.formFragment_Container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
```

So, as you can tell, I fire up fragment B from fragment A and what I don't get  is what activity hosts that fragment B, since there is no indication of main activity in this code above, nor there is indication of fragment B in main activity. Could you clarify this for me. Thanks !

Comment: The parent of the fragment B is still the activity that hosts Fragment A. You replace the content of R.id.formFragment_Container which is in Activity layout.

Comment: An activity can contain multiple fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes under the concept of nested fragments in Android.  For both Fragment A and B, its associated activity is main activity(from which you have added Fragment A).

You can access Main activity and Fragment A from Fragment B.
For example. getActivity() will return Main Activity, getParentFragment() will return Fragment A.

Answer (score 3):

When you call to

```
getFragmentManager()
```

It use instance of FragmentManager that the Activity use to manage it Fragments. So the Activity will be the same as Activity A.

Comment: That's what I've needed. Thanks.